# Magento 2 - Move Button from Middle Column to Side Bar Section

Tags: magento2, layout, template

Hello I need help moving my finance button from the middle column of the product page over to the fixed right side bar of my product page below **Add to Cart** button.

The finance button is a module provided by [Bread](https://www.getbread.com/) and I have been able to successfully identify the template that is rendering the finance button on the product page but at a loss for how to move this over to the right side bar underneath my **Add to Cart** button.

I have attempted to copy the following **block templates** from the Bread modules XML file **catalog_product_view.xml** into the layout that I believe needs to be rendered on **bestoffer_index_index.xml** but having no success.

#### Bread Module Catalog Product View XML

```
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Bread\BreadCheckout\Block\Js" as="breadcheckout.prod.js" name="breadcheckout.prod.js"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="product.info.extrahint">
        <block template="Bread_BreadCheckout::breadcheckout/view.phtml" class="Bread\BreadCheckout\Block\Product\View" as="breadcheckout.prod.view" name="breadcheckout.prod.view"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.options.wrapper">
        <block template="Bread_BreadCheckout::breadcheckout/options.phtml" class="Bread\BreadCheckout\Block\Product\View" name="breadcheckout.checkout.options"/>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

#### Ultimo Themes Catalog Product View XML

```
<head>
    <css src="mage/gallery/gallery.css"/>
</head>
<update handle="catalog_product_opengraph" />
<update handle="page_calendar"/>
<body>
    <attribute name="itemtype" value="http://schema.org/Product" />
    <attribute name="itemscope" value="itemscope"/>
    <referenceBlock name="head.components">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="checkout_page_head_components" template="Magento_Catalog::js/components.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">product</argument>
            <argument name="add_base_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="name"</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product"</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <container name="product.info.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-main" before="-">
            <container name="product.info.price" label="Product info auxiliary container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-price">
                <container name="product.info.stock.sku" label="Product auxiliary info" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-stock-sku">
                    <container name="product.info.type" before="-"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.sku" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml" after="product.info.type">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getSku</argument>
                            <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">sku</argument>
                            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">sku</argument>
                            <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">default</argument>
                            <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="sku"</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                </container>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.review" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/review.phtml" after="product.info.stock.sku" />
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render" name="product.price.final">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="price_render" xsi:type="string">product.price.render.default</argument>
                        <argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">final_price</argument>
                        <argument name="zone" xsi:type="string">item_view</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </container>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render" name="product.price.tier" after="product.info.price">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="price_render" xsi:type="string">product.price.render.default</argument>
                    <argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">tier_price</argument>
                    <argument name="zone" xsi:type="string">item_view</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <container name="alert.urls" as="alert_urls" label="Alert Urls" after="product.price.tier"/>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/form.phtml" after="alert.urls">
                <container name="product.info.form.content" as="product_info_form_content">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
                </container>
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="product.info.form.options" as="options_container">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.options.wrapper" as="product_options_wrapper" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/wrapper.phtml">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options.phtml">
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\DefaultType" name="product.info.options.default" as="default" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/default.phtml"/>
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Text" name="product.info.options.text" as="text" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/text.phtml"/>
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\File" name="product.info.options.file" as="file" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/file.phtml"/>
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" name="product.info.options.select" as="select" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/select.phtml"/>
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Date" name="product.info.options.date" as="date" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/date.phtml"/>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar" template="Magento_Theme::js/calendar.phtml"/>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom" as="product_options_wrapper_bottom" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/wrapper/bottom.phtml">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart.additional" as="product.info.addtocart" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
                    </block>
                </block>
            </block>
            <container name="product.info.extrahint" as="extrahint" label="Product View Extra Hint">
                <container name="product.info.social" label="Product social links container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-social-links">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addto" as="addto" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addto.phtml">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\AddTo\Compare" name="view.addto.compare" after="view.addto.wishlist"
                               template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addto/compare.phtml" />
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.mailto" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/mailto.phtml"/>
                </container>
            </container>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.overview" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info" after="product.info.extrahint">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getShortDescription</argument>
                    <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">short_description</argument>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">overview</argument>
                    <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
                    <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Overview</argument>
                    <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="description"</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </container>
        <container name="product.info.media" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product media" after="product.info.main">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="skip_gallery_after.target" before="skip_gallery_before.wrapper" template="Magento_Theme::html/skiptarget.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="target_id" xsi:type="string">gallery-prev-area</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <container name="skip_gallery_before.wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="action-skip-wrapper">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" before="product.info.media.image" name="skip_gallery_before" template="Magento_Theme::html/skip.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="target" xsi:type="string">gallery-next-area</argument>
                        <argument name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Skip to the end of the images gallery</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </container>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery" name="product.info.media.image" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/gallery.phtml"/>
            <container name="skip_gallery_after.wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="action-skip-wrapper">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" after="product.info.media.image" name="skip_gallery_after" template="Magento_Theme::html/skip.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="target" xsi:type="string">gallery-prev-area</argument>
                        <argument name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Skip to the beginning of the images gallery</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </container>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="skip_gallery_before.target" after="skip_gallery_after.wrapper" template="Magento_Theme::html/skiptarget.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="target_id" xsi:type="string">gallery-next-area</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </container>
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.details" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/details.phtml" after="product.info.media">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.description" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getDescription</argument>
                    <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
                    <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
                    <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Details</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attributes.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">More Information</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Cookie\Block\RequireCookie" name="require-cookie" template="Magento_Cookie::require_cookie.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="triggers" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="compareProductLink" xsi:type="string">.action.tocompare</item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="content.aside">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related" name="catalog.product.related" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">related</argument>
            </arguments>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="related.product.addto" as="addto">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                       name="related.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                       template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Upsell" name="product.info.upsell" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">upsell</argument>
            </arguments>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="upsell.product.addto" as="addto">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                       name="upsell.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                       template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Additional" name="product.info.additional" as="product_additional_data"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\ShortcutButtons\InCatalog" name="addtocart.shortcut.buttons"/>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\ShortcutButtons\InCatalog" name="addtocart.shortcut.buttons.additional"/>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block
                class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Ui\ProductViewCounter"
                name="product_viewed_counter"
                template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/counter.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Supplied is a [link to a screenshot](https://cl.ly/93b5d9f0d0da) of my template path hints along with the layout names, happy to do the work if someone can lend a hand.

Comment: did you got any solution ?

Comment: 1. Is your screenshot the **Catalog Product View** (catalog_product_view.xml) page?
2. Would you mind posting the **Bread_BreadCheckout**'s catalog_product_view.xml for reference?
3. Is bestoffer_index_index.xml a page provided by that module, or a new page you've constructed?

Comment: @floorz the code example within my question is that of the **Bread_BreadCheckout's catalog_product_view.xml**. The **bestoffer_index_index.xml** file is a custom page template that was added to the theme. For reference I am using Ultimo theme and will supply a code example for **ultimo/Magento_Catalog/layout** xml file that I believe is rendering the elements for the product page.

Answer (score 0):

Making some assumptions not having all the details needed (asked some questions in a comment on your question). I'll be happy to update my answer with more details.

### Magento 2 Layout Instructions

You can issue a `<move>` layout instruction (Reference: [Magento 2 - Layout Instructions](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#fedg_layout_xml-instruc_ex_mv)) to move a block or container to another area of a page.

**Example:**

```
<move element="name.of.an.element" destination="name.of.destination.element" as="new_alias" after="name.of.element.after" before="name.of.element.before"/>
```

### Module Layout Customization via Theme

For maintainability, it's best to keep your layout changes contained within the context they belong. In this case, the context is the Bread_BreadCheckout module since it's responsible for making this content available on the page.

You can do so by creating the following file under your theme:

**VENDOR_NAME** = The vendor of the theme you are using

**THEME_NAME** = The name of the theme you are using

In:
app/design/frontend/**VENDOR_NAME**/**THEME_NAME**/Bread_BreadCheckout/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="breadcheckout.prod.view" destination="product.info.extrahint" after="-"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggested code, but not success here. Just for clarification I have linked to my FTP folder https://www.screencast.com/t/ls0m7uT6gQK @floorz